# Google Deprecated enableSyncRendering() - Out Of Page AdUNIT Issue

Tags: google-dfp

Google has specified that after 2nd April 2019 , the enableSyncRendering() will be deprecated. We tried commenting out that line and then the Normal Ads are rendering properly.

But for Out Of Page ads i.e defineOutOfPageSlot Ad Units , The rendering of Ads is stopped.

Can anybody reply with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a code example?

Comment: + did you try witth the "enableSingleRequest" method ?